# How to disable location in android?

Tags: android

i want to switched on location like OLA cab so i am using this code:

```
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;final static int REQUEST_LOCATION = 199;public boolean noLocation() {
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        //  buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        enableLoc();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}private void enableLoc() {if (googleApiClient == null) {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

                        Timber.v("Location error " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
                    }
                }).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();

        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

        builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
                final Status status = result.getStatus();
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        try {
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            status.startResolutionForResult(
                                    (Activity) context, REQUEST_LOCATION);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_LOCATION:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED: {
                   finish();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

now it is working fine but i want to disable location using dialog, don't want to use intent for open setting screen.How is it possible?

Comment: No it is not possible, you cannot access users phone state, so you have to use Intent to stop location service